# Select the latest inserted row of a group of registers in Symfony2?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a table called **note** that is related to **budget** by `budget_id` column.

I need to select only the last inserted row for each different foreign key. I have so far this query:

```
public function findLastNotes()
{
    return $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('n')
            ->orderBy('n.id', 'DESC'
            ->groupBy('n.budget')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
}
```

But it returns the **first** register for each foreing key.

Comment: How would you know "the last"? From id?

Comment: @DonCallisto `createdAt`, probably.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need add `orderBy` for `budget` same follow:

```
public function findLastNotes()
{
    return $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('n')
            ->orderBy('n.budget', 'ASC')
            ->addOrderBy('n.id', 'DESC')
            ->groupBy('n.budget')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
}
```

Comment: Hm, I guess it did not change anything, still the first register is being shown.